# Failed to bring up eth1 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 Server

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, virtualbox

I have set up a Host-only network in VirtualBox, and created a brand new VM with Ubuntu 14.04.5 Server installed. My goal is to give the Ubuntu server a static IP address which will not change if I move to a different location with a different physical network.

In VirtualBox, using File > Preferences > Network > Host-only Networks, I created a new network: vboxnet0

```
Adapter

IPv4 Address: 10.1.1.1
IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv6 Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:0800:27ff:fe00:0000
IPv6 Network Mask Length: 6


DHCP Server
[x] Enable Server

Server Address: 10.1.1.100
Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
Lower Address Bound: 10.1.1.101
Upper Address Bound: 10.1.1.254
```

(I don't need to use the DHCP server, so I have tried with it both enabled and disabled, with the same lack of success.)

I set the Network for the Ubuntu server VM to:

```
Adapter 1: Bridged Adapter, wlan 0
Adapter 2: (enabled) Host-only Adapter, vboxnet0 (default settings)
```

When I launch the server and run ifconfig, I see only entries for eth0 with an inet addr of 192.168.1.18 (provided by the Bridged Adapter) and lo with an inet addr of 127.0.0.1.

When using a Desktop version of Ubuntu 14.04, I also see an entry for `eth1`, with an `inet addr` in the range 10.1.1.x, and I can configure this to be the static address that I want. With Ubuntu 14.04 Server, I do not see the `eth1` network.

In the Ubuntu server, I have edited `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.1.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I have also tried `eth1` with various combinations of:

```
    network 10.1.1.0
    gateway 10.1.1.1
    broadcast 10.1.1.25
```

When I run `sudo ifup eth1`, the output is:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth1
```

Does this mean that the Ubuntu virtual machine cannot see the 10.1.1.x network? Is there a command that allows me to check what networks are available?

Is there something else I need to set somewhere to make the Host-only Network visible for the VM?

Comment: Wait, so if you run a desktop you see both interfaces with `ifconfig` but if you run the server you only see one?

Comment: @meccooll That's what's been happening. Yes. Perhaps it's because I'm not looking in the right place that I don't see the other one.

Comment: It should be listed in `ifconfig -a`if it's not i'd start troubleshooting there and make sure both adapter are enabled with Vbox

Comment: @meccooll ifconfig -a does the trick. Thanks.